# iOS Quickblox error: Request failed: unauthorized (401)

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, chat, quickblox

I have been working on quickblox framework integration. I follow https://quickblox.com/developers/IOS link for integration, but unfortunately I stop at signup user step

Signup code

```
QBUUser *user=[[QBUUser alloc] init];
user.login=@"abc";
user.password=@"12345678";

[QBRequest signUp:user successBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response, QBUUser * _Nonnull tUser) {
                NSLog(@"Successfully signup:-%@",tUser);
            } errorBlock:^(QBResponse * _Nonnull response) {
                NSLog(@"Error in signup:- %@",response);
            }];
```

Every time it will return

```
error: Request failed: unauthorized (401)
reasons: {
    errors =     {
        base =         (
            "Required session does not exist"
        );
    };
}
```

How can I resolve this?

Comment: I think you missed something in integration because your same code i  checked in my swift project and it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is working code for (Swift 4)**

```
let user = QBUUser()
user.login = "abc"
user.password = "12345678"

QBRequest.signUp(user, successBlock: { response, tUser in
    print("Successfully signup:-\(tUser)")
}, errorBlock: { response in
    print("Error in signup:- \(response)")
})
```

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: have you run quickblox demo project for login and signup ?

Comment: @YogendraPatel I have done a complete project with quickblox signup, login, chat, notification, and video calling.

Comment: when you integrate quickblox?

Comment: @YogendraPatel Just before 1 Month.

Comment: @YogendraPatel Which one you used?, objective C or Swift

Comment: i have use Objective-c